# Asus 1201n will not sleep with Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu

My Asus 1201n running Kubuntu 12.04 will not sleep or suspend.

Processor is an Atom N330

Graphics aree 1st generation Nvidia Ion

Answer (score 0):

I own an asus n55, this problem seems to plague many asus models, and i think yours might be having the same problem.
heres the link to the solution, use the 1st script in the step2

http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight.  Crossing my fingers